# Converting from a Varchar in pl/sql which is more than 4000 characters to a XMLTYPE

Tags: sql, oracle

I came across a problem where I need to convert a string of more than 4000 characters to a XMLTYPE. I tried using

```
XMLTYPE.CREATEXML("MY STRING")
XMLTYPE("MY STRING")
```

In both cases, I got 'String literal too long..' error.

Answer (score 2):

We can pass only the data in xml format for creating an XMLTYPE instance and use CLOB to pass the string value and then use the EXTRACTVALUE Function to retreive the data

```
DECLARE 
str CLOB;
x XMLTYPE;
y CLOB:='<TEXT>MY STRING</TEXT>';
BEGIN
x:= XMLTYPE.CREATEXML(y);
select to_clob(extractvalue(x,'/TEXT')) into str FROM DUAL;
dbms_output.put_line(str);
END;
```

Please check the links [XMLTYPE Examples](http://www.morganslibrary.org/reference/types/xmltype.html#xmlt4) and [XMLTYPE Documantation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96616/arxml24.htm) for more practical examples

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the whole XML type returned as a Varchar you can doing the following. Here I'm selecting the whole xml value.

```
DECLARE 
str VARCHAR2(4000);
x XMLTYPE;
y CLOB:='<TEXT>MY STRING</TEXT>';
BEGIN
x:= XMLTYPE.CREATEXML(y);
str := x.EXTRACT('/').getstringval();
dbms_output.put_line(str);
END;
```

**OUTPUT:** `<TEXT>MY STRING</TEXT>`

You can drill down to child nodes also like the following.

```
DECLARE 
str VARCHAR2(4000);
x XMLTYPE;
y CLOB:='<PARENT><TEXT>MY STRING</TEXT></PARENT>';
BEGIN
x:= XMLTYPE.CREATEXML(y);
str := x.EXTRACT('PARENT/TEXT').getstringval();
dbms_output.put_line(str);
END;
```

**OUTPUT:** `<TEXT>MY STRING</TEXT>`

Finally if you just want the value you can do.

```
DECLARE 
str VARCHAR2(4000);
x XMLTYPE;
y CLOB:='<PARENT><TEXT>MY STRING</TEXT></PARENT>';
BEGIN
x:= XMLTYPE.CREATEXML(y);
str := x.EXTRACT('PARENT/TEXT/text()').getstringval();
dbms_output.put_line(str);
END;
```

**OUTPUT:** `MY STRING`